# How can I render a container / component based on the route using react-router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

My `routes.jsx` looks like

```
return (
  <Route path='/' component={Main}>
    <IndexRoute
      component={Home}
      onEnter={onSearchEnter}
      onChange={(prevState, nextState) => onSearchEnter(nextState)}
    />

    <Route path='privacy' component={Privacy} />
    <Route path='terms' component={Terms} />
    <Route path='dmca' component={DMCA} />

    <Route path='clips/:clip' component={Clip} />
  </Route>
)
```

Within my `Main`, I have something like:

```
  render () {
    return (
      <div className={`main__container ${get(this, 'props.children.type.parentClassName')}`}>
        {(() => {
          return (
            <Nav
              downloadLinks={this.props.downloadLinks}
              search={this.props.search}
            />
          )
        })()}
```

However, I don't want to render the `Nav` component if I'm in the `clips/:clip` route.

I'm using `react-router`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the *location* prop that's passed by react-router to your Main container.

It's an object in which you can find the current pathname. I'd do something like this:

```
isNavVisible = (location) => {
   return location.pathname.split('/')[1] !== 'clips';
   // location.pathname would be '/clips/someClipID'
   // => location.pathname.split('/') would be ["", "clips", "someClipID"]
}

render () {
  return (
  <div className={`main__container ${get(this, 'props.children.type.parentClassName')}`}>
    {this.isNavVisible(this.props.location) &&
      <Nav
        downloadLinks={this.props.downloadLinks}
        search={this.props.search}
      />
    }
   ...
}
```